# Is there something wrong with my current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a method to view users' posts, the posts show for any user being viewed, but in the command prompt I am getting the error

> Started GET "/feed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-20 16:04:08 -0700 Processing by UsersController#feed as / Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms
>
> `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID): in app/controllers/users_controller.rb:59:in 'feed'.`

and it keeps the rest of the action from initiating.

I think there might be something wrong with my "current user".

This is the method in my users controller

```
def feed
  @title = "Feed"
  @user = User.find(params[:id])# line 59
  feed = Feed.new(@user)
  
render 'show_feed'
end
```

This is my session helper

```
def signed_in?
  !!session[:user_id]
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

def current_user=(user) # set current user
  @current_user = user # session[:user_id] = user.id
end

def current_user?(user) # get current user
  user == current_user
end

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end
```

These are my routes

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers, :bio, :feed, :settings
    end
  end

  get '/feed', to: 'users#feed', as: :feed
```

This is the link to get the current users feed

```
<%= link_to feed_user_path(session[:user_id]) do %>
```

This is my session controller

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_back_or feed_user_path(user)
  else
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: The error is that `params[:id]` is undefined.  Can we see your routing protocol that leads to the `feed` action?

Comment: is !!session[:user_id] in your signed_in? a type?

Comment: Sorry, what's a "type"?

Comment: sorry typo ... seems strange to see !! (double negative is true)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are not signed in, you cannot see your feed. 
So the right solution should be

```
<%= link_to feed_user_path(session[:user_id]) if signed_in? %>
```

And I suggest another life-hack - add this to your sessions_helper:

```
def current_user_id
  session[:user_id]
end
```

So you can use prettier version:

```
<%= link_to feed_user_path(current_user_id) if signed_in? %>
```

Following line is unnecessary, but this should not be the problem.

```
get '/feed', to: 'users#feed', as: :feed
```

Comment: This didn't do anything. This is the error Started GET "/feed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-20 16:04:08 -0700
Processing by UsersController#feed as */*
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:67:in `feed'

Comment: Can you put <%= session[:user_id] %> next to the link? I suspect, it is nil (you are not signed_in). That's why it tries routing to /feed instead of /feed/6

Answer (score 0):

If the `current_user` is already setted you don't need to search him again. You can use the `current_user` method this way:

```
def feed
  @title = "Feed"
  feed = Feed.new(current_user) # or current_user.feeds.news(if setted relation)

  render 'show_feed'
end
```

Note that your method is not working because you are not sending the `user_id` in the get request through the route:

```
Started GET "/feed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-20 16:04:08 -0700 Processing by UsersController#feed as / Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms
```

You will have to define the route as this:

```
get '/feed/:user_id', to: 'feeds#feed' # or whatever is the controller.
```

And then you will be able to do:

```
url/feed/123
```

To search for the user with your old method.

Comment: I get a routing error when i try this, ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/feed"): When I use get '/feed/:user_id',